# With the React Rating Component, how to show a custom message based on the rating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using the [react-rating component](https://github.com/dreyescat/react-rating) to allow my users to provide a 1-5 star rating.

In my render function I have the following:

```
      <Rating
        fractions={2}
        onRate={(rate) => document.getElementById('label-onrate').innerHTML = rate || ''}
      />
      <span class="label label-default" id="label-onrate"></span>
```

This returns 5 stars, and when you hover over a star the `#label-onrate` text is updated to show the user the rating value.

What I need to do is update the text but not with the rating value but with a custom message per rating value.

How can I define a custom message per each rating value and have that message appear in `#label-onrate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an event handler for rate change and keep the label-onrate text in a state. You don't need to directly modify the DOM with React. As you update the state your components will be rerendered. Something like this:

```
  state = {
     label: "initial"
  };
  ...
  onRateChange = (rate) => {
      if(rate === 1)
         this.setState({label: "new text"}); //Triggers render
  }
  ...
  <Rating
    fractions={2}
    onRate={(rate) => this.onRateChange(rate)}
  />
  <span class="label label-default" id="label-onrate">{this.state.label}</span>
```